# Find the value of "c" wich makes it possible to solve.

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solution of 3 equations in 3 unknowns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209757/solution-of-3-equations-in-3-unknowns)

$$A=\left\{\begin{array}{c} u + v + 2w = 2 \\ 2u + 3v - w = 5 \\ 3u + 4v + w = c \end{array}\right.$$